# Uniform Choice Functions and Naturality

Tags: elementary-set-theory, category-theory, axiom-of-choice, natural-transformations

Some choice functions can be specified explicitly, while in other cases no definite choice function is known. An example of the former is a choice function for non-empty subsets of natural numbers, where one can always pick the smallest element. An example of the latter is a choice function for non-empty subsets of real numbers. A common intuition is that these explicit choice functions have uniform definitions (or at least the number of non-uniform cases must be limited). This is reminiscent of natural transformations, which can capture the idea of a morphism defined uniformly with respect to objects in a category.

Is there a way to formalize the uniformity intuition for definite choice functions? Specifically, is there some invariance/coherence condition the "pick the minimum" on the naturals satisfies that no choice function on the reals could satisfy?

Comment: It seems like by "explicit" choice function you mean a choice function that can be defined in $\mathsf {ZF}$.

Comment: AC is equivalent to "Every set can be well-ordered". When a set can be shown without AC to have a well-order (e.g. $\Bbb N$ with the usual order) then we don't need AC to "make choices". But it is consistent with ZF that $\Bbb R$ cannot be well-ordered.

Comment: Are you talking about uniformity properties like "if the choice function picks x from a bounded set S, then from $S_+={x+1 | x \in S}$ it will pick $x+1$?"

Comment: Part of my motivation for asking this question is that I'm not really sure what uniformity should mean, but that example sounds reasonable to me. At least what it picks from $S_+$ should be "determined" by some suitable type of morphism from its choice on $S$.

Comment: An explicit choice function for $L$ exists in ZF, and this is exactly how Gödel's proof that $V = L$ implies the axiom of choice works. So you cannot prove from ZF that "an explicit choice function does not exist". We only have that it is consistent that one does not exist.

Answer (score 2):

It seems like by "explicit" choice function you mean a choice function that can be defined in $\mathsf {ZF}$, without needing the Axiom of Choice.